# How to get content from new tweet before submit button is pressed?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have been wanting to develop chrome extensions for a while now (because of this idea I had with tweets). I want to be able to get the content of a new tweet before the "Tweet" button is pressed.

I then pass this message through my own js logic, and either create a popup before submitting the tweet, or let the tweet post.

Can this be achieved through a Google Chrome Extension? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: I suggest you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You will probably also want to read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).